# how to disable and enable click event with no specific handler name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of links in my app that I need to enable/disable the click event to them, but still want allow the hover and other events.

so I need a way (CSS / JS / jQuery) to disable **only** the Click event. and also with no need to use the handler name.
for example:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="runAll()" id="runAll">Run All</a>
```

JS - call to the disable function:

```
disableElement('#runAll', "no sensors to record"); // call to the disable function
```

JS - enable / disable functions

```
//disable element (add disable class and unbind from click event)
function disableElement(element, tooltip) {
    $(element).addClass('ui-disabled');
    $(element).disableClick; // need this option!

    if (typeof tooltip != 'undefined' && tooltip != "")
        loadTooltip(element, tooltip);
}

//enable element (remove disable class and bind to click eventl
function enableElement(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('ui-disabled');
    $(element).prop("title", "");
    $(element).enableClick; // need this option!!
}
```

I tried [this](https://github.com/s-yadav/eventPause.js) but didn't work for me. any idea please?

for now this is my function and

Comment: Use off ? ...like `$('button').off('click')` ... or are you talking about the event of `a` ?

Comment: but how can I enable it again? the 'on' function need the handler name for binding.

Comment: Please elaborate an example are you talking about enable with wath event and disable how ? ... and attach functions ? how aer you making the assignment ... elaborate

Comment: It would be so easier if you post a concrete sample in question to replicate your expected behaviour. BTW, ***how*** do you bind your event? Why not using referenced handler?

Answer (score 2):

With JS:

```
$(element).attr('onclick', 'return false'); // disable
$(element).removeAttr('onclick'); // enable
```

Html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return false">google</a>
```

Comment: but in you idea how can I bind the click event to my function after enabling it?

Comment: $(element).click(function() { alert('Hello'); });

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'off' call on your elements

```
$(element).off('click');
```

They can be rebound with 'on'

```
$(element).on('click', function(){
    //your handler
});
```

Comment: I cannot use this idea because the on function need also the handler name. and dont want to use the handler name

Comment: because I want the code to be clear. and the enable and disable functions to be easy to use. but of course if will be no idea how to do that without the handler name- i will add it :(

Comment: @chani you should be specific with your selectors anyway `element` should be an id or something very clear

Comment: I send the element to the function with '.' or '#'.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the handler you have for a specific event by using `$el.off('click')`.

Note though that re-attaching the event can be long winded, so it's better to use a flag within the handler itself to direct the logic. Something like this:

```
$el.click(function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.data('click-disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    else {
        // do your thing...
    }
}
```

Then you can disable/enable the handler logic by setting the `data` attribute:

```
$el.data('click-disabled', true);
```

Comment: I tried it, but my problem was with 'on' function because i dont want to use the handler name

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have a lot of links in my app. so I don't think that your idea is good because I don't want to add this functionality to all my functions (more then 10). so I am looking for a way to disable the links externally.

Comment: In that case `off('click')` will work for you, but then you will have to change the logic of your code to re-attach the events as needed.

Comment: this is my problem how to do that. I will need to bind all the links again to their functions. so what I asked is someone know about way to do that with no needing to bind again to the function.

Comment: That is why I suggested the above solution - it's *a lot* easier and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are taking the wrong approach? 
why do you want to remove the handlers if there is the possibility that you will reattach?

It might be more appropriate to have the handlers always attached, then have a check for whatever condition you feel would mean removal

i.e.

```
$('#someThing').on('click', function () {

    if(!someConditionThatYouFeelShouldRemoveTheHandler){
        // do some code here

    }

});
```

That way you dont need to attach and reattach multiple times

Comment: In your case I will need to add this check to **all** of my click function (more then 10). don't you have another idea to do that externally?

Comment: @chani An other way would be to use `$._data($('a').get(i),'events').click` in a loop but this isn't a method publicly supported

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use the event names? you said you have events on links but unless I'm missing something why bind events to lots of 'a' tags?

Comment: mmmm. if there will be no idea how to do that without the handler name I will add it. but to keep my code clearly and prevent future mistakes  I prefer not using it.

Comment: You are looking at it the wrong way, NOT using the event names doesn't make the code clear, it make it ambiguous. Code should be explicit with a clear purpose. Saying remove ALL events and add ANY previously bound event is not clean, clear or maintainable

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui-disabled').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function disableElement(element, tooltip) {
    $(element).addClass('ui-disabled');
    // do nothing

    if (typeof tooltip != 'undefined' && tooltip != "")
        loadTooltip(element, tooltip);
}

//enable element (remove disable class and bind to click eventl
function enableElement(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('ui-disabled');
    $(element).prop("title", "");
    // do nothing
}
```